# Spark MLlib packages NaN weight

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to run Spark MLlib packages in pyspark with a test machine learning data set. I am splitting the data sets into half training data set and half test data set. Below is my code that builds the model. However, it shows weight of NaN, NaN.. across all dependent variables. Couldn't figure out why. But it works when I try to standardize the data with the StandardScaler function.

```
model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(train_data, step = 0.01)  
# evaluate model on test data set
valuesAndPreds = test_data.map(lambda p: (p.label, model.predict(p.features)))
```

Thank you very much for the help.

Below is the code that I used to do the scaling.

```
scaler = StandardScaler(withMean = True, withStd = True).fit(data.map(lambda x:x.features))
feature = [scaler.transform(x) for x in data.map(lambda x:x.features).collect()]
label = data.map(lambda x:x.label).collect()
scaledData = [LabeledPoint(l, f) for l,f in zip(label, feature)]
```

Comment: Is it a standard data-set?

Comment: Hi Rishi, yes it is a standard data set with 9 predicting variables. Is it because SGD is very sensitive to feature scaling? I have some variables that are of large numbers and some variables that are of smaller numbers (for ex, one dependent variable is total revenue avg. of 1mill, the other is number of clients avg. of 5), so I need to scale them each?

Comment: Ah, there you go! That should work. I just posted that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try scaling the features

[StandardScaler](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/mllib-feature-extraction.html#standardscaler) standardizes features by scaling to unit variance and/or removing the mean using column summary statistics on the samples in the training set. This is a very common pre-processing step.

Standardization can improve the convergence rate during the optimization process, and also prevents against features with very large variances exerting an overly large influence during model training. Since you have some variables that are large numbers (eg: revenue) and some variables that are smaller (eg: number of clients), this should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Rishi, thanks for the answer. i have tried to use StandardScaler to scale each of the variable. However, when I compare the prediction errors (RMSE) to other ML packages such as sklearn, I get a significant higher error. Note sure if I am doing anything wrong with StandardScaler. I have attached the scaling code to my answer.